# Zend query greater than or equal to

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have my query which works perfectly in MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE location_id=1 AND created_at>=*timestamp*
```

I have a model for the Accounts table in Zend. I used

```
$accounts->where(array('location_id' => 1))
```

and when I try to use another where clause

```
->where("created_at >= $timestamp")
```

Zend throws me this error:

```
"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 7"
```

I have also tried to hardcode my `$timestamp` variable, delete the first `where` and use just the second one, and even tryed to change the syntax to

```
->where("created_at >= " . $timestamp)
```

None of them worked. Any ideeas?

**LATER EDIT**

I figured it out, it seems it was a syntax problem. This worked for me:

```
where("created_at >= '$timestamp'");
```

Comment: Looks like there's a problem generating in SQL query. Try printing query by `$select->__toString()`, and post it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
->where("start >= ?", $timestamp)
```

(in ZF1). Also, in the query you said works perfectly the column is named `created_at`.

Comment: Yep, my bad. I work with columns different from what I have wrote here, for the example purpose.